# Why does git branch info clear upon making a new tab in terminal

Tags: bash, git, terminal.app

I've written a bash script to put git info into my bash prompt, along with still keeping the terminal's pwd in the title bar, to allow for new tabs to be opened at the current working directory. It all works well except that when I make a new tab the it info in the original tab clears until I click enter to refresh it.

Below is my entiere `.bash_profile`

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

function git_prompt() {
  local status=`git status 2>&1`

  if ! [[ $status =~ "Not a git repository" ]]; then
    # get the current branch
    local branch=`git branch | ack -o '(?<=\* ).*'`

    # set the color according to the status of the git repo
    if [[ $status =~ "nothing to commit" ]]; then
      local color=42
    elif [[ $status =~ "nothing added to commit but untracked files present" ]]; then
      local color=43
    else
      local color=45
    fi

    echo -ne "\033["$color"m"$branch"\033[49m "
  fi
}

function my_prompt() {
  ## PWD IN TITLE FOR NEW TAB LOCATION DETECTION
  update_terminal_cwd

  ## GIT BRANCH AND STATUS DISPLAY
  git_prompt
}


## SETTINGS ############################################################
########################################################################

# custom bash prompt
PS1='\[\e[1;34m\]\W \$\[\e[0m\] '

# scripts that need to be run before display of bash prompt 
PROMPT_COMMAND=my_prompt
```

Answer (score 3):

This basically happens because while loading `~/.bashrc` it doesn't consider to properly include `~/.bash_profile`

Just append these lines at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, it should do the magic.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Works for me well :)